# Text hidden behind my Bootstrap 5 Side Navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a side NavBar(with Bootstrap 5) which I achieved but my text is being hidden behind the navbar. Any tips on how I can fix this?

This is my code for side Navbar:

```
const Navbar = ({ handleClick, isLoggedIn, email }) => (
  <>
    <nav
      className="navbar navbar-expand d-flex flex-column align-item-center-start"
      id="sidebar"
    >
      <a href="/" className="navbar-brand text-light mt-8">
        <div className="display-6 font-weight-bold">
          <span>TESTING</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul className="navbar-nav d-flex flex-column w-100">
        <li className=" h-25 nav-item border-bottom">
          <a href="/" className="nav-link text-light pl-4">
            HOME
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="h-25  nav-item border-bottom">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link text-light ">
            SEARCH
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item h-10 border-bottom">
          <a href="/show" className="nav-link text-light ">
            PODCASTS
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item h-25 border-bottom">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link text-light pl-4">
            YOUR LIBRARY
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item h-25 border-bottom">
          <a href="/login" className="nav-link text-light pl-4">
            LOGIN
          </a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item h-25 border-bottom">
          <a
            href="#"
            onClick={handleClick}
            className="nav-link text-light pl-4"
          >
            LOGOUT
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    {isLoggedIn ? (
      <LoggedInNav
        handleClick={handleClick}
        isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
        email={email}
      />
    ) : (
      <div>
        {/* The navbar will show these links before you log in
        <a href="/login">Login(Spotify)</a>
        <Link to="/signup">Sign Up</Link> */}
      </div>
    )}
  </>
);
```

and my CSS:

```
.navbar {
  width: 210px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  /* margin-left: -300px; */
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

This is what my app currently looks like : [image: My current home page]

You can see the password form, but my username form is blocked by my navbar.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position: fixed;` removes this element from the normal content flow.
This means that the element can now be on top (or under) other elements and is relatively positioned to the `body`.

If you want to display both besides each other, you're best bet would be to have another flex container around (instead of a fragment).

Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mclean-tpropv

```
/* React */
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <nav className="nav">Hello World</nav>
      <div className="other">Login Form</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
/* CSS */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  width: 210px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.other {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works! I've been trying to get login & logout to the bottom of the sidebar instead of being where it is seen in the picture. Any tips on this too? I tried everything i found online.

Comment: I've adjusted the example to include some elements in the bottom part of the sidebar :)
Here's an article about flexbox, this can help you out https://medium.com/the-andela-way/understanding-css-flexbox-87cddcd3d1e4